# Return to parent activity from child activity when reopening from Android history

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-pendingintent

My application allows the users to browse around in certain child activities `FileListActivity` owned by a parent `MainActivity`. When the user clicks e.g. home button, the app goes to background.

**Problem:**

When the user opens the app via `PendingIntent` or from history, the child activity `FileListActivity` is shown. Pressing the back button from here closes the app (sends app to background).

**Visualized flow:**

1. *Open app*
2. `MainActivity` opens
3. user opens child `FileListActivity`
4. user clicks home button
5. user opens app from Android history
6. user clicks back button

App goes to background, but `FileListActivity` should close and return to `MainActivity`

**Question:**

Using something like

`startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FileListActivity.class));`

How can I ensure that when the user reopens the app onto the child activity and presses the back button that the app returns to `MainActivity` and doesn't go to background?

*I know I should be using [IntentFlags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#addFlags(int)), just not sure which to use.*

Comment: still not getting "How can I ensure that when the user reopens the app onto the child activity and presses the back button that the app returns to MainActivity and doesn't go to background?" this is the default behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS` may do the trick

Or

You `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`.

refer the android dev for more info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

Comment: startActivity was sending to background, startActivityForResult ensured I returned to calling activity, thanks